# Xcode Quick Help only showing "Declared In" information. Issue with docsets?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, documentation

Xcode Quick Help is only showing me "Declared In" information after I downloaded the latest DocSet under the Xcode menu Preferences => Downloads => Documentation.

The Quick Help now has nothing else. It is missing all the other information except for the "Declared In" information.

Now, I have the following docsets in the folder ~/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets

```
com.apple.ADC_Reference_Library.DeveloperTools.5_1.docset
com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleOSX10.9.CoreReference.docset
com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiOS7.1.iOSLibrary.docset
```

I found some information on this from a Google search but nothing that is particularly this problem. It seems like Xcode is getting confused about which docset to use?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode just crashed and after I restarted, the other information on Quick Help is now displayed.